# Find out if records exists after limit

Tags: laravel

So I am wondering is there any other way to know if any record exists after limit?

For example, I only need to fetch 20 results, but I also need to know if there is more records left after that limit so that I could add one more page for my pagination:

```
User::query()->limit(21)->get();
```

This is what I am doing now, but I don't like it because I am fetching one extra result to know if it has more records.

Would appreciate any possible solutions.

I am not using `simplePaginate` method. But as I know `simplePaginate` says if more records exists to display other page.

Comment: How about doing a count query?

Comment: What I should count? My fetched limit?

Answer (score 0):

Try paginate() instead of limit

Comment: No `paginate` no `simplePaginate` method I will be using

Answer (score 0):

To get the total number of collections on your table, you can get the total by:

```
$totalUser = User::count();
```

Suppose, this returns 500. That mean's you have currently 500 Users.

And then you need to take first 20 rows. Then you can write code like:

```
$users = User::query()->limit(20)->get();
```

The second one will get the 20 rows. Then if you write a condition like this:

```
if($totalUser > $users->count()) {
    // Write code here considering have more data on your users table
}
```

Comment: But using `count` on all database is not good for performance. Lets say we have 1million rows and you count them all, at this point I dont see any better solution than fetching one more result.

Comment: This is another option to `skip` and then `take` a single data to optimize the solution.
For example:
```
$nextUsers = User->skip(20)->take(1)->count();

if($nextUsers > 0) {
    // Do whatever you want now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the application, and the size of a model, in rare cases, there may be more efficient to find one more model than you need.

For example, needing to limit search for 21 items, we find 22 items, such as:

```
User::query()->limit(22)->get();
```

From the found count, you can determine, whether there were more than 21, and remove the last item, not needed by your application (preferably by quitting iteration sooner, for performance)

Now, this may be very inefficient, if the model is big, however, in case of lightweight model, we execute only one query, as the proposed solution to count the database content

```
$totalUser = User::count();
```

can indeed be very costly! If we consider database with milions of records, or even in hundreds of thousands, moreover, two sql aueries would be executed (one for count, other for the selection). However, here we are delving into the actual implementation details of the eloquent laravel framework.

So, as always, use a debug bar, look at the times it takes to execute the queries, and decide for yourself, which solution is more feasible from the perspective of the runtime, also considering your data count.

Answer (score -1):

try counting before you fetch as @cerlin suggested, like so

```php
$count_of_all_records = User::all()->count;

// or you can fetch your 20 records but also check if the next exists on the fly
$more_is_left = User->where('id', 1)->exists();
```

if you are not using pagination.

Comment: Okay with this I have another question. What if we have a lot of records in database and we counting them all will it take less performance time than fetching one more extra result ?

Comment: it will depend on the columns per record that you are fetching and how large the data they hold is, from a performance perspective counting doesn't fetch anything  it only execute one query, so it will not affect the performance at least not significantly.

Comment: why would you pull all the records from the database (`all`) and hydrate all the models to put in a collection to just get a count, when you could call `count` directly on the query?